# wso2 enterprise integrator Class filter get parameter

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I have installed WSO2 EI 6.1.1 on a Linux box. I have created a pass through proxy for a rest interface that gets both GET and PUT requests. I have set a Java Class Mediator that is supposed to make some deicisions based on a parameter included in the url of the requests:

```
http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8280/services/app/url?token=ABCD
```

When I ask for the context of the request from the class I can see the content of the envelope and the resquest.

```
System.out.println("Context: \n " + context.getMessageString());

 To : /services/app/url?token=ABCD
MessageID : urn:uuid:431940fd-201e-43a3-aad1-0ca5e36297dd
Body : <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Body/></soapenv:Envelope>
```

How can I get the value of the token parameter? No way I have tried has worked.

---

UPDATE:

This is the current sequence:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sequence name="jsonvalidate" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <log>
        <property expression="get-property('query.param.token')" name="token"/>
    </log>
    <property name="pass" scope="default" type="STRING" value="yes"/>
    <property expression="get-property('query.param.token')"
        name="token" scope="default" type="STRING" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"/>
    <class name="authzMediator.validate">
        <axis2ns15:property name="validated" value="1" xmlns:axis2ns15="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"/>
        <axis2ns16:property name="validated1" value="yes" xmlns:axis2ns16="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"/>
    </class>
    <log category="DEBUG">
        <property expression="get-property('token')" name="token1" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"/>
    </log>
    <filter xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" xpath="get-property('pass') = 'yes'">
        <then>
            <class name="authzMediator.trace">
                <axis2ns17:property name="msg" value="YES" xmlns:axis2ns17="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"/>
            </class>
        </then>
        <else>
            <class name="authzMediator.trace">
                <axis2ns18:property name="msg" value="NO" xmlns:axis2ns18="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"/>
            </class>
            <drop/>
        </else>
    </filter>
</sequence>
```

What I see is that in the first step (log) I see this:

```
[EI-Core]  INFO - LogMediator To: /services/lsrest/clients/jordipc/3/0/14?token=patata, MessageID: urn:uuid:3b08226e-4a46-474a-8d7c-c4c786e51b4c, Direction: request, token = null
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final result was based on a double action:

1. Define a property mediator with an expresion value `$url:token`and name "token".
2. In the Class mediator call this function `context.getProperty("token")`

Answer (score 1):

You can access the value of the token parameter with get-property('uri.var.token') [1].

There are two approaches to using this value.

(1) Pass token as a parameter to the class mediator.
Follow [2] for a sample.

(2) Access this property in the class mediator `mediate()` method as below.

```
token = synCtx.getProperty('uri.var.token');
```

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/HTTP+Endpoint
[2] https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/Class+Mediator

Comment: I am not sure if I am doing it correctly. I have created a property with name token and expresion (get-property('uri.var.token')) and tried to get the value from the class with (context.getProperty("token")). I am getting NULL value. What is wrong?

Comment: Can you log the uri.var.token before passing to the class mediator to see whether it is set properly first?

Comment: INFO - LogMediator To: /rest/path?token=pptttpptt, MessageID: urn:uuid:84909eeb-962b-4ac9-9c86-18cf07ce976c, Direction: request, token = null

Comment: Since this is a query param and not a url param, try setting the query param property as  <property name="token" expression="get-property('query.param.token')"></property>